Can I hide the lengthy filepath in PyCharm terminal?
I initiated a new project in PyCharm and the filepath's length in terminal takes up to the half of the screen width. Is there a way to hide that filepath?

Thank you in advance
I explored the interface, searched in the browser for the resolution but to no avail
